# Find the number of trees on $2m$ given vertices in which all vertices have degree $1$ or $3$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> **Problem**: Find the number of trees on $2m$ given vertices in which all vertices have degree $1$ or $3$.

**My attempt**: We know that for a tree $T$, we have $2(n-1) = \sum _ { v \in T } d ( v )$, with $n$ the number of vertices and $d(v)$ the degree of a vertex $v$. We can call $n_k$ the number of vertices of degree $k$. Hence we have that $$2(n_1+n_3-1)=n_1+3n_3$$
and $$2m=n_1+n_3$$.

From this we can conclude that either $n_1$ and $n_3$ are both even, or both odd. Now we also now that $n_3=n_1-2$. One can easily check an example, with $n_1=3, n_3=3-2=1, n_1+n_3=2\cdot 2$, we do have a star graph with 3 leaves and a center of degree 3.

**My question**: now I have a formula to draw such trees, but I don't have the number of trees for a given $2m$ vertices. Maybe I could calculate the number of pairs $(n_1, n_3)$ such that the sum is even. Can someone help me conclude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using  Pruefer codes  we have  that the  leaves of  degree one  do not
appear  in the  code  at  all.  Therefore  the  code  consists of  two
appearances of all nodes of degree three. As the length of the code is
$2m-2$ there are  $m-1$ such nodes. Hence we choose  these, and select
two slots for each in turn, proceeding in order. This yields

$${2m\choose m-1} \frac{(2m-2)!}{2^{m-1}}.$$

This gives the sequence

$$1, 4, 90, 5040, 529200, 89812800, 22475653200,
\\ 7791559776000, 3576325937184000, 2100278686746240000, \ldots$$

which points us to [OEIS A274056](http://oeis.org/A274056) where these
values are confirmed.

Comment: Could you explain $\frac { ( 2 m - 2 ) ! } { 2 ^ { m - 1 } }$? If I try to identify, $( 2 m - 2 ) !$ is the number of permutation in the Pruefer but what is $2^{m-1}$? And why are we dividing $( 2 m - 2 ) !$?

Comment: Simpler perhaps: There is also an explicit formula for the number of trees on $n$ vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$ such that these vertices have degrees $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$, respectively: Namely, this number is $\dfrac{\left(n-2\right)!}{\left(d_1-1\right)! \left(d_2-1\right)! \cdots \left(d_n-1\right)!}$ (assuming that $n \geq 2$). This formula can be easily proven by induction if you don't like the Prüfer code. Now, we can use this formula to see that the number of trees on $2m$ vertices $1,2,\ldots,2m$ such that these vertices have degrees $1,1,\ldots,1,3,3,\ldots,3$, respectively ...

Comment: (with $m+1$ times $1$ and $m-1$ times $3$), is $\dfrac{\left(2m-2\right)!}{\left(1-1\right)!^{m+1} \left(3-1\right)!^{m-1}} = \dfrac{\left(2m-2\right)!}{1^{m+1} 2^{m-1}} = \dfrac{\left(2m-2\right)!}{2^{m-1}}$. But this counts only those trees whose first $m+1$ vertices $1,2,\ldots,m+1$ have degree $1$ and whose last $m-1$ vertices $m+2,m+3,\ldots,2m$ have degree $3$. Since you want to count all trees having $m+1$ vertices of degree $1$ and $m-1$ vertices of degree $3$, you need to multiply this result by $\dbinom{2m}{m+1}$, since that is the number of ways to choose $m+1$ out of $2m$ given ...

Comment: ... vertices. (I am using the fact that if a tree on $2m$ vertices has only vertices of degrees $1$ and $3$, then it has exactly $m+1$ vertices of degree $1$ and exactly $m-1$ vertices of degree $3$. This is because in any tree, the sum of the degrees of all vertices is twice the number of edges, but the latter number is the number of vertices minus $1$.)